# Hide certain columns for certain sizes?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation. My nav bar currently takes up 3 columns, with my content taking up the rightmost 9 columns.

For size `small`, I'd like to only show those 9 columns. I'd like all the proportions to stay exactly the same.

Is there any way to simply 'hide' the first 3 columns, so that I can keep all my sizes the same (e.g. `medium-3 medium-3 medium-3`), but the 9 columns now take up the full page width?

Another option I see is to set total columns to 36, and do all the math so the columns end up being the same, but this seems less ideal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/visibility.html) (this link is for Foundation 6; [click here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/visibility.html) if you're using Foundation 5). Have a read, because this page has many useful visibility options.

You can achieve the result you want by **hiding for small only** (Foundation 5 & 6):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns hide-for-small-only">
    <!-- navigation bar -->
  </div>
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <!-- main content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

or by **showing for medium and larger** (Foundation 6):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns show-for-medium">
    <!-- navigation bar -->
  </div>
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <!-- main content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

or by **showing for medium and larger** (Foundation 5):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns show-for-medium-up">
    <!-- navigation bar -->
  </div>
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <!-- main content -->
  </div>
</div>
```